# On Click of button change Text inside <script> tags using jquery or javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Below is the code in which `changeme` is the text i want to change on the click of the button.

HTML code and JS is below:

1) whatever user input in field will be capture and replace with `changeme` if the JavaScript and then with the new JavaScript page is loaded.

If someone will help me it will be really great help

```
<form>
Stream ID: <input id="csi" name="q" placeholder="Custom Streame Id">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="View">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer("test").setup({
       aboutlink: "http://domain.com",
       abouttext: "DOMAIN",
    streamer: 'link',
    file:'changeme'

   });
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so when the user click submit, you want the input value will be replaced with "changeme" (e.g. the file link?)

Comment: no... but user.. will put some new value like XYZ in the input tag and hit submit. that XYZ should change    javascript code file:'XYZ'

Comment: hence script code already loaded into the page. so we need when someone click submit it changes and loads with new.

Answer (score 0):

To change the playing file dynamically use the `load()` function:

```
jwplayer().load("newfile").play();
```

Comment: Well i will definitely  look into this what you mean .

Answer (score 0):

Base on DevZer0 solution, you can try this

```
<form>
Stream ID: <input id="csi" name="q" placeholder="Custom Streame Id">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="View" onclick="loadnewfile();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer("test").setup({
       aboutlink: "http://domain.com",
       abouttext: "DOMAIN",
    streamer: 'link',
    file:'ORIGINAL_FILE'    
   });

   function loadnewfile(){
      jwplayer().load($('#btn').val()).play();
   }
</script>
```

Assuming you have jQuery loaded in the document.

Comment: thanks alvin. I have tried this and i jave jquery loaded too.. but some reason its not working ..

Comment: I am using jwplayer 6.1.2972  ..  I am not sure whats wrong in here... how do i change ORIGINAL_FILE <---

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("container").setup({
 file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/i8oQD9zd-640.mp4",
 image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/i8oQD9zd-640.jpg",
 title: "Tears of Steel"

 });
 function playTrailer(key) { 
 jwplayer().load([{
 file: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/"+key+"-640.mp4",
 image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/"+key+"-640.jpg"
 }]);
 jwplayer().play();
 }
 function playstream(key) { 
 jwplayer().load([{
 file: "+key+",
 streamer: 'rtmp://hideipforsecurity/golive',
 type:'rtmp'

 }]);
 jwplayer().play();
 }
 </script>

   <p>Live Streamers:</p>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="javascript:playTrailer('i8oQD9zd')">Tears of Steel</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:playTrailer('3XnJSIm4')">Sintel</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:playTrailer('bkaovAYt')">Big Buck Bunny</a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:playstream('idx')">stream</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Above is what I achieved. Now when I click  `stream` it gives me an error in jwplayer:

> ERROR PLAYING list : no playable source found.

If anyone knows whats wrong help me.